# pulling data from mysql and counting/grouping within query

Tags: mysql

I need some help pulling some data from a table in mysql. I have several ways to do this that are long and not efficient but I know there is a cleaner way. I have a table, call it books, that has a memberid field and a status field. The status field can be 0,1,2,3. I need to pull all the rows by memberid ( this is for a specific member, not all members, so I will send it a memberid ) and get a total of each status for that memberid supplied. I know this doesnt work, but this is sort of what I am trying to do in regular terms.

```
SELECT memberid
     , count(status) as pending where status= 0
     , count(status) as approved where status= 1
     , count(status) as completed where status= 2
     , count(status) as denied where status= 3
  FROM `books` WHERE memberid = 1
```

I know I can do several queries to pull this info as well as pull everything with that members id and rip through the array in php to get the info but I feel there is a way to do this that is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this kind of query frequently this way:

```
select memberid, 
  sum(status = 0) pending, 
  sum(status = 1) approved, 
  sum(status = 2) completed, 
  sum(status = 3) denied 
  from books where memberid = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Strawberry - I've never used that syntax before.